# Windows - Low on Registry space

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, networking, thin-client

The system has reached the maximum size allowed for the system part of the registry. Additional storage requests will be ignored.

I am getting this message on my thin-client server, and the OS is windows 2003 enterprise edition. Even users are getting the error messages( http://goo.gl/CcJ1F ).

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the sizes of the registry hives in:

   - *C:\windows\system32\config*

Security ____ MB

Software ____ MB

System ____ MB

Default ____ MB

- *C:\Documents and Settings*

Default User ____ MB

LocalService ____ MB

NetworkService ____ MB

User Profiles ____

Each individual User Profile sizes ____ MB (Sometimes the median and biggest size can be enough).

```
2. Make sure that you don’t have the following registry key set:   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\RegistrySizeLimit

3. If you don’t have the registry key set, install the latest UPHClean (2.0) in http://blogs.technet.com/uphclean/, set the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UPHClean\Parameters\SHARING_VIOLATION_REMAP (dword) 1 (hex), then stop and restart the UPHClean Service
```